# Destacar dia e semana em Calendário

Tags: javascript

Como ***destacar (estilizar)*** o **dia do mês** e a **semana**?

A função mais abaixo foi a mais simples que consegui na Web que me permite entender pelo menos parte do código. Preciso saber 1) como aplicar CSS ao dia atual e 2) ***acessar***, ***alterar*** e ***estilizar*** a semana).

O objeto `Date()` permite acesso ao ano, mês e dia, mas não tem um método direto que devolva a semana (série de dias de Domingo a Sábado), de modo que se possa me referir a ***semana atual***, ***anterior*** ou ***posterior***, assim como se faz em `getDate() - 1`, por exemplo.

Ao ***acessar e alterar a série de dias da semana desejada***, quero ***estilizá-la*** de alguma forma (`tag <tr>`) em CSS para dar destaque, como na imagem abaixo.  Ex: 15 a 21 de Julho **OU** 29 de Julho a 4 de Agosto.
[image: 1ª imagem]

Além disso, caso a ***semana anterior/posterior*** for ***parte do mês passado/seguinte***, teria de ***exibir os dois meses***, lado a lado, (*como na imagem abaixo*).
Ex: Se hoje fosse 3 de Novembro, como destacado na imagem abaixo, uma referência à ***semana passada*** pertenceria ao mês de Outubro (dias 24 a 30), tornando necessário os dois meses em questão a fim de ***exibir o dia atual*** e ***a semana anterior***.

[image: 2ª imagem]

### Observações:

A *estilização da semana* deve ser ***arbitrada***, abrangendo uma única linha inteira (`tag <tr>`), assim como na 1ª imagem (dias 15-21). Por arbitrada me refiro a ser capaz de ***passar um valor à função*** que retorne 1) ***semana atual***, 2) ***semana passada***, 3) ***semana retrasada***, 4) ***semana seguinte***, ou 5) ***semana após a semana seguinte*** (assim como `getDate() - 1` retorna o dia de ontem), independente do dia atual (24, na 1ª imagem), que serve apenas para referência, com o objetivo de ***identificar 1 dentre*** essas ***5 possibilidades*** de semanas no Calendário. Daí a necessidade de às vezes isso incluir um segundo mês (2ª imagem), devido a diferença entre *dia atual* e a *semana desejada*.

### O objetivo principal é destacar o dia do mês e a linha `<tr>` da semana desejada, não importa se isso for  ou não realizado acessando as semanas do jeito que eu expliquei.

```
<body>

<style>
.week {
outline: solid 1px red;
}
</style>

<div id='cal'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Calendar(id, year, month) { 
  var elem = document.getElementById(id)
  var mon = month - 1
  var d = new Date(year, mon)
  var weekDay = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  var months = ['January', 'Frebruary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  var table = ['<table><tr>']

  table.push('<th colspan = 4>' + months[mon] + '</th>' + '<th colspan = 3>' + year + '</th>' + '</tr><tr>')
  for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++ ) {
    table.push('<th>' + weekDay[i] + '</th>');
  }
  table.push('</tr><tr>')

  for (var i=0; i<d.getDay(); i++) {
    table.push('<td></td>')
  }
  while(d.getMonth() == mon) {
    table.push('<td>'+d.getDate()+'</td>')
    if (d.getDay() % 7 == 6) {
      table.push('</tr><tr>')
    }
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)  
  }
  for (var i=d.getDay(); i<7; i++) {
    table.push('<td></td>')
  }
  table.push('</tr></table>')
  elem.innerHTML = table.join('\n')
}
new Calendar("cal", 2015, 2);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Você pode colar imagens diretamente no corpo da questão. Imagens em links externos, tendem a cair com o tempo.

Comment: Poderia mostrar o que você já fez?

Comment: @eden, opcionalmente você pode usar a blibioteca MomentJS para manipular a data: http://momentjs.com.
Você pode olhar o seguinte jsPerf: https://jsperf.com/moment-js-vs-native-date/4

Answer (score 5):

## Obter dia atual

Em JavaScript, para obteres o dia atual usas o método [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate):

```js
var hoje = new Date().getDate();
```

## Obter semana indicada

Para obter a semana indicada em JavaScript, no decorrer da construção das linhas da tabela, podemos verificar ao abrir uma nova `<tr/>` se a mesma corresponde à semana que pretendemos destacar:

```js
// ...

var weekNum=0;

// ...

if (d.getDay() % 7 == 6) {

    // a variavel de controlo a ser incrementada
    weekNum++;

    // se for igual à semana indicada, aplicar classe de CSS
    if (weekNum == highlightWeek) {
        table.push('</tr><tr class="highlightWeek">');
    }
    else {
        table.push('</tr><tr>');
    }
}

// ...
```

---

## Exemplo

O teu código pode então ficar da seguinte forma:

```js
function Calendar(id, year, month, highlightWeek) { 

    var elem  = document.getElementById(id),
        mon   = month - 1,
        d     = new Date(year, mon),
        today = new Date().getDate();

    var weekDay = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

    var months = ['January', 'Frebruary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    var table = ['<table><tr>']
    
    table.push('<th colspan = 4>' + months[mon] + '</th>' + '<th colspan = 3>' + year + '</th>' + '</tr><tr>')
    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++ ) {
        table.push('<th>' + weekDay[i] + '</th>');
    }
    table.push('</tr><tr>')
    
    for (var i=0; i<d.getDay(); i++) {
        table.push('<td></td>')
    }

    var weekNum = 1;

    while (d.getMonth() == mon) {

        var tdClass1 = today==d.getDate() ? 'curDay' : '';

        table.push('<td class="'+tdClass1+'">'+d.getDate()+'</td>');
        
        if (d.getDay() % 7 == 6) {

            weekNum++;

            if (weekNum == highlightWeek) {
                table.push('</tr><tr class="highlightWeek">');
            }
            else {
                table.push('</tr><tr>');
            }
        }

        d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
    }
    for (var i=d.getDay(); i<7; i++) {
        table.push('<td></td>')
    }
    table.push('</tr></table>')
    elem.innerHTML = table.join('\n')
}

new Calendar("cal", 2015, 3, 2);
```

```css
.curDay {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.highlightWeek{
    background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div id='cal'></div>
```

O exemplo em cima está também disponível no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/vrmb5rd5/).

Comment: Ele estiliza após o dia atual, e ás vezes abrange linhas diferentes. Deveria estilizar a linha `<tr>` inteira junto com a opção de definir qual linha estilizar. Atualizei a pergunta com mais detalhes. Desculpe não ter feito uma pergunta mais clara da primeira vez.

Comment: @eden Desculpa a demora, não me tinha apercebido da tua alteração da pergunta. Atualizei para ficar como pretendes.